# Damn Small Linux Commands

Tags: linux

I am using dsl 3.4.12 with Oracle VM virtualbox. What are the commands to compile and run lex programs in dsl terminal?
Like we use lex filename.l and to run gcc lex.yy.c -ll in ubuntu and telnet.

Comment: `apt-get install flex gcc`?

Comment: I am getting this error while enabling apt.

Calling the dpkg restore script...
Grabbing the compressed dpkg database and programs...
Connection to www.ibiblio.org[152.2.210.81]:80
wget: server returned error 404: HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found
Download error!

what to do for this?

Answer (score 0):

Install mysql Extensions of `flex` and `gcc`. [How to here](http://www.damnsmalllinux.org/wiki/installing_mydsl_extensions.html)

For manual installation download `.dsl` file for gcc and flex from [here](http://distro.ibiblio.org/damnsmall/mydsl/system/) and run:

```
mydsl-load <extention>.dsl
```